# Insertion of new nodes in a Tree

Tags: c++, tree, insertion

I want to code a class named *tree* for creating the *Data Type* **Tree** . I want a function inside class *tree* which will automatically create nodes and insert values in nodes level-wise( row-wise ).
For this I have also created **Queue** Data Type to store addresses of the *left* and *right* of a node which is being filled .
But when I traverse the tree using  **preOrder Traversal** I just found **1** printed on my screen.
❤️ Help me in this context.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct treeNode;

struct node{
    treeNode * address;
    node * next;
};

class queue{
    node *front, *rear;
    public:
    queue(){
        front=NULL;
        rear=NULL;
    }
    void enQueue(treeNode *& item){
        node *temp=new node;
        temp->address=item;
        temp->next=NULL;
        if(front==NULL){
            front=temp;
            rear=temp;
        }
        else{
            rear->next=temp;
            rear=temp;
        }
    }
    treeNode *& deQueue(){
        treeNode *& temp=front->address;
        front=front->next;
        return(temp);
    }
} Q;

struct treeNode{
    int data;
    treeNode * left;
    treeNode * right;
};

class tree{
  public:
    treeNode * root;
    tree(){
        root=NULL;
    }
    void iTree(int item){
        treeNode *temp=new treeNode;
        temp->data=item;
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        if(root==NULL){
            root=temp;
            Q.enQueue((root->left));
            Q.enQueue((root->right));
        }
        else{
            treeNode *& Temp=Q.deQueue();
            Temp=temp;
            Q.enQueue(Temp->left);
            Q.enQueue(Temp->right);
        }
    }
};

void preOrder(treeNode *root){
    if(root!=NULL){
        cout<<root->data<<" ";
        preOrder(root->left);
        preOrder(root->right);
    }
}

void main(){
    tree T;
    T.iTree(1);
    T.iTree(2);
    T.iTree(3);
    T.iTree(4);
    
    preOrder(T.root);
    
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, step by step, one line at a time, and monitor the values of all variables, what did you see?

Comment: I find it very hard to answer this question. I entirely fail to see what the point of the Queue thing is. Also, it's very suspect that you have only one Queue no matter how many trees there are - it seems to be shared.

Comment: Also, it appears that you **always** call `Q.enQueue(nullptr)`, since you're always calling it with the `temp->left` and `temp->right` which you always initialize to `nullptr` after creation.

Comment: @MSalters I suspect the queue is intended to store references to the pointers where new elements should be placed in the tree to get O(1) insertion time – having missed that the `node` type would have had to store `treeNode**` pointers to make that work properly.

Comment: SO is not  a code writing service, you wouldn't be learning anything if we did so for you. Even if we did, you'd have to clarify first what you actually want to achieve, see questions above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// Prortotypes
struct treeNode;

// Queue required for Tree
struct node{
    treeNode *address;
    node *next;
};

class queue{
    node *front, *rear;
  public:
    queue(){
        front=NULL;
        rear=NULL;
    }
    void enQueue(treeNode *);
    treeNode * deQueue();
} Q;
void queue::enQueue(treeNode *item){
    node *temp=new node;
    temp->address=item;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(front==NULL){
        front=temp;
        rear=temp;
    }
    else{
        rear->next=temp;
        rear=temp;
    }
}
treeNode * queue::deQueue(){
    treeNode *temp=front->address;
    front=front->next;
    return(temp);
}

// Node of Tree
struct treeNode{
    int data;
    treeNode *left;
    treeNode *right;
};

// Implementating TREE Data Structure
class tree{
    treeNode *root;
  public:
    tree(){
        root=NULL;
    }
    void insertTree(int);
    treeNode * rtnRoot();
    
};

// Insert function 
// (To insert new nodes in Tree)
void tree::insertTree(int item){
    treeNode *temp=new treeNode;
    temp->data=item;
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->right=NULL;
    if(root==NULL){
        root=temp;
        Q.enQueue(root);
        Q.enQueue(root);
    }
    else{
        treeNode *TEMP=Q.deQueue();
        if(TEMP->left==NULL){
            TEMP->left=temp;
            Q.enQueue(TEMP->left);
            Q.enQueue(TEMP->left);
        }
        else{
            TEMP->right=temp;
            Q.enQueue(TEMP->right);
            Q.enQueue(TEMP->right);
        }
    }
}
// root return function
treeNode * tree::rtnRoot(){
    return(root);
}

// preOrder Traversal
void preOrder(treeNode *root){
    if(root!=NULL){
        cout<<root->data<<" ";
        preOrder(root->left);
        preOrder(root->right);
    }
}

// Main function
void main(){
    tree T;
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        T.insertTree(i);
    }
    
    preOrder(T.rtnRoot());
}
```

I was doing a mistake earlier.
I was storing left and right of a node and they are always initialized to NULL pointer . This time I'm storing the address of the node twice in the queue so that I may store values in the left and right of that node.
See code for more clarity.
Sorry for ridiculous explanation but I figured it out . Thanks to the community for support.